# How to wrap a bash script so that it will correctly handle quotes and boolean operators

Tags: linux, bash, wrapper

I am trying to create a wrapper command that will:

- move to a different folder
- change the current user
- clear env variables

So far I created this `/bin/app`:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/www/backend

if [[ $# == 0 ]];
then
  exec chpst -u application env -i PATH="$PATH" /bin/bash
else
  exec chpst -u application env -i PATH="$PATH" "$@"
fi
```

But I keep getting errors when running this commands:

```
app bin/console d:m:m
app bin/console d:m:m && sleep 10
app bin/console acme:bar "multi word data" "another multi word data"
```

First command just runs `bin/console` without parameters.
The second command shows error `&& command not found`.
I also need support for cases like in third command.

What is the correct way to create a wrapper that works with more complex commands?

If this changes anything I need those to work inside docker eg.

```
docker-compose exec app app bin/console d:m:m
docker run acme/foo app bin/console d:m:m
```

Comment: You cannot pass shell syntax as individual arguments. What you could do instead is collect a single string and add `-c 'shell script string' ` to the shell

Comment: I tried `exec chpst -u application env -i PATH="$PATH" /bin/bash -c "$@"`  as well but it didnt work.

Comment: to expand multiple arguments or array entries into a single string value you need to expand with the star instead of the @ `$*`

Comment: But will `$*` work with multi word variables like in my third example?

Comment: Yes with using single-quotes like this: `app bin/console 'acme:bar "multi word data" "another multi word data"'`

Answer (score 1):

This would work for you

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/www/backend || exit 1

# Pass argument 1 as shell script path and default to /bin/bash if none
shell_path="${1:-/bin/bash}"
shift
# Collect argument 2 and following arguments as shell script
shell_script="$*"

exec chpst -u application env -i PATH="$PATH" "$shell_path" -c "$shell_script"
```

Example usage:

```sh
app bin/console 'acme:bar "multi word data" "another multi word data"'
```

Another much cleaner option would be to pass the shell script as stdinput or a filename:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/www/backend || exit 1

# Pass argument 1 as shell script path and default to /bin/bash if none
shell_path="${1:-/bin/bash}"
shift
# collect file name as argument 2. Use - for stdin if no file name
shell_file="${1:--}"

exec chpst -u application env -i PATH="$PATH" "$shell_path" <(
  cat "$shell_file"
)
```

Example usage:

```sh
# here-string stdin
app bin/console <<<'acme:bar "multi word data" "another multi word data"'
```

Stored in a file `console.script`:

```
acme:bar "multi word data" "another multi word data"
```

Then:

```sh
app bin/console console.script
```